# adjust custom url using url manager yii php

Tags: php, yii

i have url like

```
localhost/abc.com/info/c/q/Best%20Men
```

here info is the controller and c is action and q is query id.

i want to re write these url dynamically by removing c/q/ and using non space url. For instance like this

```
localhost/abc.com/info/Best_Men
```

is it possible using urmanager???

i tried this code but it didnt work

```
'info/c/<q:\d+>'=>'info/<q:\d+>',
```

[AFTER EDIT]

My config contained this

```
'urlManager'=>array(

    'urlFormat'=>'path',
'showScriptName'=>false,
 'caseSensitive'=>false,
    'urlSuffix'=>'.html',    

        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'rules'=>array(

            'info/<q:\w+>' => 'info/c'

                ),
    ),
```

For more explaination here is what are my urls

```
http://localhost/abc.com/mycontroller/myactionsearch?q=Best
```

it returns me lists of searched items and on clicking any link it opens for e.g. clicking best men open this below link

```
http://localhost/abc.com/mycontroller/myactionItem/q/Best%20Men
```

so actually i have two different actions within same controller and now i want to make it run like

```
http://localhost/abc.com/mycontroller/Best%20Men
```

or

```
http://localhost/abc.com/mycontroller/myactionItem/Best%20Men
```

but it gives page not found error using above config

Comment: page not found error could occur when you have not got the correct query string (in your case, the value of `q`), so check the value of `q` that your action ultimately sees. you could also check server error_log to check what url is exactly being called. i'm just guessing.

Answer (score 1):

That route is wrong for several reasons:

- it does not match the specific query (`\d` means "digit", so it won't match "Best_Men")
- it does not forward to a valid controller action
- the pair of values should be switched around

Instead of this you want something more similar to

```
'info/<q:\w+>' => 'info/c'
```

Comment: Its not working , i need to to make the query value as a url path like i wrote above. What steps should i use to make it work according to localhost/abc.com/info/Best_Men

Comment: also how can i specify valid action because the one you wrote contained only controller and query.

Comment: this should work. wolvorinePk, what is your current urlManager config? you want _info/best_men_ to work, so this rule matches that and forwards it to `info/c`, where `c` is the action and best_men is `q`

Comment: in my url manager this is written 

'urlManager'=>array(
  
  'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'showScriptName'=>false,
     'caseSensitive'=>false,
  'urlSuffix'=>'.html',    
  
   'urlFormat'=>'path',
   'rules'=>array(
    
    'info/<q:\w+>' => 'info/c'

Comment: I have url that works like localhost/abc.com/info/c/q/Best%20Men
 but problem is i need to hide Action and query both. and only i want to show localhost/abc.com/info/Best%20Men but instead. So as above answer i have used 'info/<q:\w+>' => 'info/c' but using this gave me page not found error. Please check my url config in my question which i have edit now.